# Trying to get property of non-object - laravel

Tags: laravel

I am tring to do now is to make a many to many relation between "payments" table and "invoices" table ... but my problem is when i try to add a new payment and i select e list of invoices laravel gives me " Trying to get property of non-object " in line 217 ..

this is my code :

$selectedInvoices = $input['invoice'];

```
    $invoices = collect([]);
    foreach ($selectedInvoices as $invoice) {
        $invoices = $invoices->merge([Invoice::find(Invoice::getPrivateId($invoice))]);
    }
    $invoices->all();

    $invoices = $invoices->sortByDesc(function($invoice)
    {
        return $invoice->invoice_date;
    });
    $invoices->values()->all();

    $totalAmount = 0;

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
    {
        $totalAmount = $totalAmount + $invoice->balance;
    }

    if($payment->amount > $totalAmount){
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
            $adjustment = $invoice->balance * -1;
            $partial = max(0, $invoice->partial - 0);
            $invoice->updateBalances($adjustment, $partial);
            $invoice->updatePaidStatus();
            $payment->invoices()->attach($invoice->id) ;
        }
        $credit = Credit::createNew();
        $credit->client_id = $clientId;
        $credit->amount = $payment->amount - $totalAmount ;
        $credit->balance = $payment->amount - $totalAmount ;
        $credit->credit_date = $payment->payment_date;
        $credit->private_notes = 'Crédit créé automatiquement suite au payement '.$payment->id.
        ' avec un montant de '.$payment->amount.' à la date de '.$payment->payment_date;
        $credit->save();
    }

    if($payment->amount <= $totalAmount)
    {
         /*line 217*/   while ($payment->amount >= $invoices->last()->balance){
            $payment->amount = $payment->amount - $invoices->last()->balance ;

            $adjustment = $invoices->last()->balance * -1;
            $partial = max(0, $invoices->last()->partial - 0);
            $invoices->last()->updateBalances($adjustment, $partial);
            $invoices->last()->updatePaidStatus();

            $payment->invoices()->attach($invoices->last()->id) ;

            $invoices->pop();
            $invoices->all();
            }

        if ($payment->amount < $invoices->last()->balance){
            $adjustment = $payment->amount * -1;
            $partial = max(0, $invoices->last()->partial - $payment->amount);

            $invoices->last()->updateBalances($adjustment, $partial);
            $invoices->last()->updatePaidStatus();
            $payment->invoices()->attach($invoices->last()->id) ;
        }
    }
```

p.s: when i give an amount > total amount of my invoices it works also when i give an amount < total amount it works too ..

Comment: What is the code on line 217? Can you highlight it in the code that you have posted?

Comment: if($payment->amount <= $totalAmount)
    {
         /*line 217*/   while ($payment->amount >= $invoices->last()->balance){.....

Comment: Check your `$invoices->last()` at that line.. Obviously it doesn't exist, most likely due to popping items off. Besides that, you're using `->all()` and `->values()` all over the place, but those methods return something, they do not change the collection itself. Also instead of doing foreach for the total amount check `->sum('balance)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch line 217

**From:**

```
while ($payment->amount >= $invoices->last()->balance){
```

**To:**

```
while (count($invoices) && $payment->amount >= $invoices->last()->balance) {
```

Explanation: `$invoices->pop()` is removing the last item in the collection. When all the items have been removed from the `invoices` collection, no `invoice` object will be found; Hence, the **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: it gives me the same exception in this lineif ($payment->amount < $invoices->last()->balance)

Comment: Same as before, just add the `count($invoices)` :)